# how to get the caret position in react js?

Tags: reactjs

In any event in react you can get `event.pageX` or `event.clientX` to get the latest position of the mouse cursor, what about the caret position? in `<div contentEditable><div>` or `texture` or `input` you will tow different pointers one is the caret inside the element and the other is the curser, I know how to get the cursor position but I have no idea how to get the caret ( I beam typing pinter) position?

Answer (score 2):

try something like this,

```
// its basically any `input`, `textarea` tag
const input = document.getElementByTagName('input');
let Ipos = null

if (input.selectionDirection === 'forward')
  Ipos = input.selectionEnd 
else if (input.selectionDirection === 'backward')
  Ipos = input.selectionStart

// else direction unknown
```

See [HTMLInputElement MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Comment: what the variable or const `input` came from ?

Comment: @alial-karaawi `input` is basically any **input**, **textarea**, but not **contentEditable**'s

Comment: aga thank you, but that don't work in `<div contentEditable`